# For what reasons could a message without flags not be returned in an UNDELTED search query?

Tags: office365, imap

I'm fetching messages from office365 through an IMAP search query "UNDELETED" and it doesn't return any results. However, when I search "ALL", I do get ids back, and when I fetch their flags, it's not showing any flags.

What could be causing this and how should I fix it?

Comment: I suggest reporting that as a bug in office365.

Comment: I don't think they have a public bug tracker.

Comment: And I can see why they might make that choice. Sigh.